# Linq to object Performance issue?

Tags: asp.net, performance

I have 10 millions of records in my table. I'm trying to fetch records by using linq query,
but this cause performance issue. How can I fetch data without any delay or any performance issue?

Comment: Does your table have an index to support your query?   If you are locating one record in 10 million without an index -- then the DB has to read  the whole table to find it.

Comment: yes. DB has to find..what is the best way to implement.. and i have to send mails to these records

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumerable.Skip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) and [Enumerable.Take](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) to implement paging for getting data using LINQ. For faster access you may re-visit your current **[indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index)** *(if you have any)*,  on data and try loading only required data/columns.

You may see: [Effective Paging Using Linq (Sample Code) - Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/458801/Effective-Paging-Using-Linq-Sample-Code)

If you are only going to search for records in the database and select only few of them and you are worried about performance then it would depend more on your database server. LINQ query against a data source translates into under laying query language. If your under laying data source is SQL Server then LINQ gets translated into SQL. You can get the generated SQL via [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) or Visual studio and see if it needs optimization by looking at it [query execution plan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_plan). You may also setup indices against the column you want to search in your LINQ query, that will greatly improve records selection from 10 million rows.

Comment: @geeta, it totally depends on your requirement and skill set. If you are comfortable in LINQ and sure that your expression would generate an optimized query then go for LINQ otherwise go for SP.

Comment: but first thing is performance.. if it take less time through sp then we ll prefer that one

Comment: @geeta, yes generally SP would give you a better performance but you should see this [Stored procedures are evil](http://www.tonymarston.co.uk/php-mysql/stored-procedures-are-evil.html) :)

Comment: the main thing is i have to send mail to 10 million records. By triggers can i achieve this?

Comment: @geeta, what does trigger has to do with record selection ?

Comment: when i am inserting 10 million records then i can send mail

Comment: but main concern is for existing records

Comment: some body suggest me NOSQL DB. i am doing R& D on that